# Groupby mean in pandas python

Tags: python, mean, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file consisting of 5 fields.
Some sample data:

```
market_name,vendor_name,price,name,ship_from 
'Greece',03wel,1.79367196,huhif,Germany
'Greece',le,0.05880975,fdfd,Germany
'Mlkio',dpg,0.11344859,fdfd,Germany 
'Greece',gert,0.18655316,,Germany
'Tu',roland,0.52856728,fdfsdv,Germany 
'ghuo',andy,0.52856728,jhjhj,Germany
'ghuo',didier,0.02085452,fsdfdf,Germany 
'arsen',roch,0.02578377,uykujkj,Germany
'arsen',dpg,0.10010169,wrefrewrf,Germany 
'arsen',dpg,0.06415609,jhgjhg,Germany
'arsen',03wel,0.02578377,gfdgb,Germany 
'giar',03wel,0.02275039,gfhfbf,Germany
'giar',03wel,0.42751765,sdgfdgfg,Germany
```

In this file there are multiple records for every vendor. I want to find every unique value of the field `vendor_name` and also calculate the average `price` for each vendor. I am using the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from random import randint

ds = pd.read_csv("sxedonetoimo2.csv", 
                 dtype={"vendor_name": object, "name" : object, 
                        "ship_from" : object, "price": object})

ds['ship_from']=ds.ship_from.str.lower()
print(ds.dtypes)
pd.to_numeric(ds['price'], errors='coerce')

d = { 'name': pd.Series.nunique,
      'ship_from' : lambda x: randint(1,2) if (x==('eu'or'europe'or'eu'or'europeanunion'or'worldwide'or'us'or'unitedstates'or'usa'or'us'or'ww'or'wweu'or'euww'or'internet')).any() else randint(3,20)
      ,'price': ds.groupby('vendor_name')['price'].mean()
      }

result = ds.groupby('vendor_name').agg(d)

result.to_csv("scaled_upd.csv")
```

But I am getting this error :

> raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
>   pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

In my csv file, the values of the field price is only numbers. If I change the type of that field to `float` , it raises an error that a specific string cannot be parsed. I am really confused. Any help?

Comment: Do you just want `ds.groupby('vendor_name').agg({'price': 'mean'})`?

Comment: Sounds like you have bad data in the CSV but need more info. What specific string can't be parsed?

Comment: @rahlf23 the thing is that apart from the mean of the price field, I also need the number of the unique values of the field name.

Comment: Can you include a sample dataframe? It will be much simpler to provide you a thorough answer with sample data to work with.

Comment: `market_name, vendor_name, price,name, ship_from

'Greece',03wel,1.79367196, huhif ,Germany
'Greece',le,0.05880975,fdfd,Germany
'Mlkio',dpg,0.11344859,fdfd,Germany
'Greece',gert,0.18655316,,Germany
'Tu',roland,0.52856728,fdfsdv,Germany
'ghuo',andy,0.52856728,jhjhj,Germany
'ghuo',didier,0.02085452,fsdfdf,Germany
'arsen',roch,0.02578377,uykujkj,Germany
'arsen',dpg,0.10010169,wrefrewrf,Germany
'arsen',dpg,0.06415609,jhgjhg,Germany
'arsen',03wel,0.02578377,gfdgb,Germany
'giar',03wel,0.02275039,gfhfbf,Germany
'giar',03wel,0.42751765,sdgfdgfg,Germany`

Comment: If it is not readable, I can also upload a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `read_csv()`, `groupby()` and `agg()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv').groupby('vendor_name') /
    .agg({'price': 'mean', 'name': lambda x: x.nunique()})
```

Yields:

```
                price  name
vendor_name                
03wel        0.567431     4
andy         0.528567     1
didier       0.020855     1
dpg          0.092569     3
gert         0.186553     0
le           0.058810     1
roch         0.025784     1
roland       0.528567     1
```